# XSLT: how to return results from a key, in order specified

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to select elements based on a number in their "title" element and then return them in a specific order. I've grouped them using a key, but when I access they key and apply-templates to the nodes, they're not being returned in the order specified.

sample code:

```
<test>
    <anElement>
        <title>001 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>002 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>003 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>004 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>005 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>006 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>007 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>008 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>009 title</title>
    </anElement>
    <anElement>
        <title>010 title</title>
    </anElement>   
</test>
```

when transformed with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="keyNodes" match="//anElement" use="title/substring(., 1, 3)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <groupsOfNodes>
       <aGroup>
           <title>group one</title>
        <members>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('keyNodes', ('003', '002', '001'))"/>
         </members>
       </aGroup>
        <aGroup>
            <title>group one</title>
            <members>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('keyNodes', ('010', '009', '008'))"/>
            </members>
        </aGroup>
    </groupsOfNodes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="anElement">
    <para><xsl:apply-templates/></para>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives this result:

```
<groupsOfNodes>
   <aGroup>
  <title>group one</title>
  <members>
     <para>001 title</para>
     <para>002 title</para>
     <para>003 title</para>
  </members>
  </aGroup>
   <aGroup>
  <title>group one</title>
  <members>
     <para>008 title</para>
     <para>009 title</para>
     <para>010 title</para>
  </members>
   </aGroup>
  </groupsOfNodes>
```

Here's an example of the desired result:

```
    <members>
     <para>003 title</para>
     <para>002 title</para>
     <para>001 title</para>
  </members>
```

Is there any way to specify the order they're processed, or do I have to use separate "apply-template" rules for each node in the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your code to

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="keyNodes" match="anElement" use="title/substring(., 1, 3)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <groupsOfNodes>
       <aGroup>
           <title>group one</title>
        <members>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="for $s in ('003', '002', '001') return key('keyNodes', $s)"/>
         </members>
       </aGroup>
        <aGroup>
            <title>group one</title>
            <members>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="for $s in ('010', '009', '008') return key('keyNodes', $s)"/>
            </members>
        </aGroup>
    </groupsOfNodes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="anElement">
    <para><xsl:apply-templates/></para>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you are using XSLT 2.0 I also wonder why you use keys for grouping but that is a different issue.